# Is it possible to avoid .await with Elastic4s

Tags: async-await, elastic4s

I'm using Elastic4s (Scala Client for ElasticSearch).

I can retrieve multiGet results with await :

```
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(esHosts, esPort))
val resp = client.execute {
  multiget(
    get(C1) from "mlphi_crm_0/profiles" fetchSourceInclude("crm_events"),
    get(C2) from "mlphi_crm_0/profiles" fetchSourceInclude("crm_events"),
    get(C3) from "mlphi_crm_0/profiles" fetchSourceInclude("crm_events")
  )
}.await
val result = resp.items
```

But I've read that in practice  it's better to avoid this ".await".
How can we do that ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use .await because you're blocking the thread waiting for the future to return.

Instead you should handle the future like you would any other API that returns futures - whether that be reactive-mongo, akka.ask or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old, but in case anyone else comes across it, the simplest way to handle this would be:

```
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(esHosts, esPort))
val respFuture = client.execute {
  multiget(
    get(C1) from "mlphi_crm_0/profiles" fetchSourceInclude("crm_events"),
    get(C2) from "mlphi_crm_0/profiles" fetchSourceInclude("crm_events"),
    get(C3) from "mlphi_crm_0/profiles" fetchSourceInclude("crm_events")
  )
}

respFuture.map(resp=> ...[do stuff with resp.items])
```

The key thing here is that your processing actually takes place in a subthread, which Scala takes care of calling for you when, any only when, the data is ready for you.  The caller keeps running immediately after `respFuture.map()`.  Whatever your function in `map(()=>{})` returns is passed back as a new Future; if you don't need it then use `onComplete` or `andThen` as they make error handling a little easier.

See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html for more details on Futures handling, and https://alvinalexander.com/scala/concurrency-with-scala-futures-tutorials-examples for some good examples